# Load balancing router can't connect to VPN

Tags: windows-xp, router, vpn, load-balancer

I'm working on Windows XP Pro.

I have 2 internet connections - one cable, one ADSL - and I'm trying to hook up using a load balancing router (D-Link DI-LB604).  Everything is working just great - except I can't connect to my work VPN.  If I plug my computer directly into either the cable or ADSL modem, I connect just fine using the native Windows VPN connection; as soon as I hook up through the load balancer, I cannot connect to the VPN (error 800).

There must be some secret switch on the load balancer that allows me to dial in to the VPN - but what?

I tried lookup up support on D-Link's web site, but their [support section](http://www.dlink.com/support/) is very scant on details, the product has been discontinued, so they don't support it over the phone, and the [forums](http://forums.dlink.com/) are a complete maze of useless topics, none of which appears to be about getting tech support.

Any ideas or pointers how to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Tools->Misc" page of the router configuration I found a setting "PPTP Passthrough", and "Enabled" was set to false.  I checked the "Enabled block, and Bob's your uncle!

Answer (score 1):

See this thread: [VPN Pass-through not working on D-Link DI-524](http://fixunix.com/networking/37500-vpn-pass-through-not-working-d-link-di-524-a.html).

I quote:

> I don't have the same router, but on
>   my router dir-655, you will need to
>   set this in the virtual server list...
>
> Gre:
>  Under traffic type, the
>   protocol is "Other", and set to 4. The
>   public and private field should greyed
>   out. Ip, is ip to your server.
>
> pptp:
>  Under traffic type, the
>   protocol is "TCP", and set to 6. The
>   public and private field is set to
>   1723. Ip, is ip to your server.
>
> Make sure your software firewall
>   allows this. (you can disable it)
>   Make sure in the ALG section that pptp
>   is checked. (all the options there
>   should be already checked by default)

Does this help?

Comment: +1 not exactly what I'm looking for, but as a result of looking for the settings you described I did find some kind of secret switch which I'll describe in my own answer.

Comment: That's why I quoted the above - in order to start you on the way to the right setting. Remark: The right etiquette is to add your own info in your post, and credit the person who put you on the right path.